# How to call intent method from java using flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-intent, autostart

So I am trying to make my app auto-start So to do this i have to redirect the user to the auto start screen of the devices. I tried calling intent similar as we get the battery detail app in flutter but it's not working, [how to make app autostart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473230/android-how-to-enable-autostart-option-programmatically-in-xiaomi-devices/56335831#56335831) any guidance will be helpful.[github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52531)

what I am looking for an alternate way of using
this **intent to open auto-start screen in oppo**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setClassName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                                "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
```

this is for Xiaomi

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter",

   "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
                startActivity(intent)
```

this intent in flutter. I already looked into [flutter intent](https://pub.dev/packages/intent)

Comment: I don't understand why to downvote its never been asked and I don't find the solution

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: So i am asking that in android we can ask the user to make the app come under auto start through flutter whereas in the flutter those intent are not there so i have to call native intent through flutter but that is not working

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot i have updated the question

Comment: Can you please write your question again, in a most understandable manner? I find it hard to get what you're actually struggling with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your question. You can try the following for Xiaomi devices

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('com.myapp/intent');

void openAutoStartSettings() async {
    await platform.invokeMethod('com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity');
}
```

For other manufacturers, please check this post https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/48166206/how+to+start+power+manager+of+all+android+manufactures+to+enable+background+and+push+notification

Comment: I will try this and let you know

Comment: there is no method called invokeMethod in platform

Comment: the following link is for java i already mentioned the intent list in the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking but to start an app from a flutter app you can use this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appavailability

here an exemple to open the mailBox app

```
try{
  AppAvailability.launchApp(Platform.isIOS ? "message://" : "com.google.android.gm").then((_) {
    print("App Email launched!");
  }).catchError((err) {
    print(err);
  });
} catch(e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Comment: No, I don't want to open any app I just want to open a specific screen in the settings through intent for that i need an intent related solution as we can not open settings without using intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [android_intent library](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) for launching external app. Documentation has some sample codes.
You may use sample code below.

```
var map={"AuthParams":authParam};
var intent=AndroidIntent(package:"in.app",arguments: map,componentName: "in.app.ui.splash.SplashActivity",/*action: "action_view"*/);
await intent.launch();
```